# How to Wrap first and second word in two italic with jQuery

Tags: jquery

This is my code:

```
jQuery('.n2-ss-item-content').each(function(){
    var me = jQuery(this);
    me.html(me.html().replace(/^(\w+)/, '<i>$1</i>'));
});
```

The HTML output is showing this:

```
<i>Majesty</i> Purple | 24” w x 20” h | SOLD
```

Suppose to be it should be like this:

```
<i>Majesty Purple</i> | 24” w x 20” h | SOLD
```

Comment: first of all `.each()` will not work properly with `id`. You need to use `class`. otherwise in each iteration it will do stuff on the first-one only

Comment: i already changed it to class

Comment: What type of result you are getting from the above code?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to just take whole phrase before `|`? You wouldn't have to worry about word count, because what if your first phrase will be 3 words or 1 word?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
jQuery('.n2-ss-1item1').each(function(){
    var me = jQuery(this);
    me.html(me.html().replace(/^([^|]+)/, '<i>$1</i>'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="n2-ss-1item1">Majesty Purple | 24” w x 20” h | SOLD</p>

<p class="n2-ss-1item1">Majesty Blue | 24” w x 20” h | SOLD</p>
```

Comment: Thanks @Alive to Die

Comment: @vince  i have changed my code for the consideration that may be 3 or 4 or more words can exist before first `|`. You can check now. More accurate. Glad to help you :):)

Answer (score 2):

You need to include whitespace with the regex along with the word characters or use negated character class to avoid `|`, like `^([^|]+)`. In addition to that, you can use [`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html-function) with a callback(the second argument is old HTML content) and which iterates internally and updated content with the returned value.

```
jQuery('.n2-ss-item-content').html(function(_, html){
    return html.replace(/^([\w ]+)/, '<i>$1</i>');
});
```

or

```
jQuery('.n2-ss-item-content').html(function(_, html){
    return html.replace(/^([^|]+)/, '<i>$1</i>');
});
```

```js
jQuery('.n2-ss-item-content').html(function(_, html) {
  return html.replace(/^([\w ]+)/, '<i>$1</i>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="n2-ss-item-content">Majesty Purple | 24” w x 20” h | SOLD</p>
<p class="n2-ss-item-content">Majesty Blue | 24” w x 20” h | SOLD</p>
```